# How to expand an ImageView when clicked to fit the screen?

Tags: android, imageview

I want `ImageView` start expanding to fit the screen (it would be great including some animation with) when `ImageView` is clicked. Although i've found a great sample to show.

This is the default scene:

[image: Default]

and when user clicked in the image:

[image: When Clicked]

How can I approach this solution? Any code example will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Comment: i did try it out but it does not work for different image sizes @Bryan

Comment: Then I think you should create a fragment and pass the image data to that fragment and that fragment should contain imageview and do it using scaleType

Answer (score -1):

In order to view the image in a full screen after clicking the image. We need a create a new Activity (or) dialog fragment which makes our work easier in design and coding aspect also. To achieve this we can directly use intent and pass the url to the full screen activity and from their we can use a image loader to download and show it fully. Remember in your case background of the fullscreen activity should be transparent.

If you want to do some animation for this transition means, I would recommend you to use the **shared element transition** for this. The following link will help you to achieve this,

[Link 1](http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition)

[Link 2](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/)

Hope these links will guide you in achieving your requirement :)